# TabPages in accordance to CheckedListBox

Tags: c#, tabcontrol, tabpage

I have a tabcontrol with 4 tabpages.I have a Checked list box with 8 items.I want to open the tabpages which were checked in the checkedlistbox.I tried like this.

```
      private void clbScenario_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
        if (clbScenario.SelectedIndex == 0 || clbScenario.SelectedIndex == 1 || clbScenario.SelectedIndex == 2 || clbScenario.SelectedIndex == 3 || clbScenario.SelectedIndex == 4)
        {
            tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tp1);

        }
        else
            HideTabPage(tp1);
        if (clbScenario.SelectedIndex == 5 || clbScenario.SelectedIndex == 8)
        {
            tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tp2);
            //ShowTabPage(tp2);
        }
        else
            HideTabPage(tp2);
        if (clbScenario.SelectedIndex == 6)
        {
            tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tp3);

        }
        else
            HideTabPage(tp3);
        if (clbScenario.SelectedIndex == 7)
        {
            tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tp4);

        }
        else
            HideTabPage(tp4);
    }
```

But the result is not as i thought.Please help me anyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `ItemCheckEventArgs e` not the `CheckedListBox` itself. `e.index` is gonna give you which item is checked/unchecked and `e.CurrentValue` is gonna give you wheter is checked/unchecked. What you need to consider is if the `e.CurrentValue` is `unchecked` that means it's actually gonna be `checked` because this is showing value of the control before the process.

```
private void clbScenario_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Index >= 0 && e.Index <= 4)
    {
        if (e.CurrentValue.ToString() == "Unchecked") tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tp1);
        else HideTabPage(tp1);
    }        
    else if (e.Index == 5 || e.Index == 8)
    {
        if (e.CurrentValue.ToString() == "Unchecked") tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tp2);
        else HideTabPage(tp2);
    }        
    else if (e.Index == 6)
    {
        if (e.CurrentValue.ToString() == "Unchecked") tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tp3);
        HideTabPage(tp3);
    }        

    else if (e.Index == 7)
    {
        if (e.CurrentValue.ToString() == "Unchecked") tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tp4);
        else HideTabPage(tp4);
    }
}
```

Comment: Error-------'System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'index' and no extension method 'index' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Sorry it's gonna be `I` , not `i`. Edited